# Drupal 7 Migrate Module shows "No migration groups defined". Why is my Migration Class not registering?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration, database-migration, data-migration

I am trying to migrate content (at this point user accounts specifically) from a legacy site into Drupal 7 using the [Drupal Migrate module](http://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) but for some reason the custom site migration class is not being registered. The only indication that something is wrong is the lack of **any** output when running `drush migrate-status`, and the output **"No migration groups defined"** when visiting `http://<drupal_root_url>/admin/content/migrate` in a web browser. The `migrate`, `migrate_ui`, and `pinpics_migration` modules have all been enabled via the Drupal 7 admin dashboard. I have tried using drush to clear all caches and register the migration classes, as well as registering the migration classes using the web UI to no avail. drush was run from the folder with the settings.php file `/<drupal_root_path>/sites/default/`

```
drush cc all && drush migrate-register && drush migrate-status
```

I have the following files located in

```
/<drupal_root_path>/sites/all/modules/custom/pinpics_migration/
```

- pinpics_migration.info
- pinpics_migration.migrate.inc
- pinpics_migration.module

I have tried placing the file containing the custom migration class implementation `pinpics_users.inc` in the same directory as the files above, as well as in:

```
/<drupal_root_path>/includes/
```

Here are the file contents:

**pinpics_migration.info**:

```
<?php
name = "Pinpics Migration"
description = "Module to migrate legacy site to Drupal 7 site"
package = "Migration"
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = migrate
files[] = pinpics_migration.module
files[] = pinpics_users.inc
?>
```

**pinpics_migration.migrate.inc**:

```
<?php
function pinpics_migration_migrate_api() {
    $api = array( 'api' => 2 );
    return $api;
}
?>
```

**pinpics_migration.module**:

```
<?php
define("SOURCE_DATABASE", "pinpics_db");
?>
```

**pinpics_users.inc**: (Stripped of some helper functions, and specific implementation details)

```
<?php
/// Stripped some helper functions that were used by pinpicsUserMigration::prepareRow() below

class pinpicsUserMigration extends Migration {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(MigrateGroup::getInstance('user_migration_group'));
        $this->description = t('Migrate pinpics.com users');

        $source_fields = array(
            'uid' => t('User ID'),
            'roles' => t('The set of roles assigned to a user.'),
            'password' => t('MD5 hash of User Password'),
            'email' => t('User email address'),
            'name' => t('Username'),
            'created' => t('Timestamp that legacy account was created.'),
            'status' => t('The staus of the User account'),
            'logintime' => t('Timestamp that the User last logged in.')
        );

        $query = db_select(SOURCE_DATABASE.'.users', 'u')
            ->fields('u', array('uid', 'roles', 'password', 'email', 'name', 'created', 'logintime', 'status'))
            ->condition('status', '0', '=')
            ->condition('inactive', '0', '=')
            ->condition('email', '', '<>')
            ->condition('loginip', '', '<>')
            ->orderBy('uid', 'ASC');

        $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query, $source_fields);
        $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationUser(array('md5_passwords' => TRUE));

        $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
            array(
                'uid' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'unsigned' => TRUE,
                    'non null' => TRUE,
                    'description' => 'Legacy Unique User ID',
                    'alias' => 'u',
                )
            ),
            MigrateDestinationUser::getKeySchema()
        );

        $this->addFieldMapping('uid', 'uid');
        $this->addFieldMapping('name', 'name');
        $this->addFieldMapping('pass', 'password');
        /// Many addFieldMapping() statement stripped out for brevity.
    }

    public function prepareRow($current_row) {
        /// Stripped implementation details for massaging data to prepare for Drupal 7.
        return TRUE;
    }
}
?>
```

I am new to Drupal, and have been using the following references to implement the migration.

[Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 via Migrate 2](http://dtek.net/2012/04/27/drupal-6-to-drupal-7-via-migrate-2.html)

[Getting started with Migrate](http://www.drupal.org/node/1006982)

Has anyone encountered this problem before, or know how to go about finding out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Visit your sites modules page `/admin/modules` to trigger rebuilding of cached PHP.
- Disable and enable your module to get a new class registered.